# How to post HTML form data to Facebook application hosted on my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a WordPress theme for Facebook timelinecover. When user click set us timelinecover, the url of the image posted to the Facebook application for sharing it to wall. I don't know how to send the image url to my facebook application.

The form is hosted in my website,the app hosted separately. When I send the form data to the app, if the user is not logged on Facebook or not authenticated the app, when the user authorise and allow the permission, the submitted form data become lost.

If the user is already authenticated and logged in,the form data passed to the app successfully

NB: the form is hosted on my website, when the user submit the form, I want to pass the data (timeline image url) to my Facebook app.

Here is my code:

html form

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="get" action="index.php"
<input type="hidden"value="http://security.singlelinelogics.com/wpcontent/uploads/2012/12/aDs-164.jpg"name="cover">
<input type="submit">
```

Index.php

```
<?php
require_once("config1.php");
$cover = $_REQUEST['cover'];
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$fbuser = $facebook->api('/me');
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$photo = $facebook->api("/{$ALBUM_ID}/photos", "post", array(
'message' => 'Photo caption',
'url'   => "$cover"
 ));      
 $url = "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?preview_cover=".$photo['id'];
  ?>
```

Config.php

```
 <?php
    require_once("fb/facebook.php"); 

    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = '450616291663048';
    $config['secret'] = '088834ee0ffd3dbb332747e087b95e99';

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $redirecturi = "http://template.singlelinelogics.com/tintumon/";
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if(empty($user['id'])){
    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos',
            'redirect_uri'  => $redirecturi
        )
    );

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
       }
    $fbuser = $facebook->api('/me');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it why you need to pass the form data to FB app. If you really wanted to use the data entered in your form in your app, you can do it by first directing the user to FB app and after he authorizes your app, you can redirect him to your html form.

As far I know, creating an FB app would be to retrieve certain details regarding that user. If you really wanted to do something with that user's profile, I guess you need to first direct him to your app and then do your operation.

Comment: Buddy,iam developing a wordpress theme,timline cover posting theme,when user click the post,there is a button to share the timeline cover to wall.i cant setup facebook app script in the post,because its not possible to give redirect url in facebook app,because its a wordpress theme,so the only way is to setup app separately,and get the image url of the cover and pass it to the app for sharing when user click setas timeline cover

Comment: Xprogrammer,the simplest way of achieving your goal is to store it in a session variable($_SESSION['url'] in php),then u can hit the FB server for app authorization and when you reach your destination page(redirect_uri), then u can retrieve them from session in same manner and post it on user`s wall.